# iOS - Why build failed on simulator, but success on device/Generic iOS Device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a doubt, when we set target device and build a normal working project then it builds success, but same project when I change target to simulator OR Generic iOS Device  then it fails. I have shared screen shot for error details when I build a working project on simulator. What's the reason behind this  **why same code builds + runs perfectly on iphone devices OR Generic iOS Device, On the other hand fails on simulator?** Please note that, **I have added already necessary Framework in my project.** Any suggestion will be great. Thanks guys.

**https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJTim.png**

Comment: You need to add `#import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>` probably you can find the solution by your self like just google it with error  '_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKStoreProductViewController",` referenced from:' you get what framework missing so add thouse framework that error goes  away

Answer (score 1):

it means the supporting frameworks are missed

for `_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKStoreProductViewController`

add  **StoreKit framework**

for `_OBJC_CLASS_$_asidentifiermanager`

add  **AdSupport.framework**

for `_OBJC_CLASS_$_CMMotionManager`

add

**CoreMotion.framework**

Comment: @  Nitin Gohel  and Anbu.Karthik, **So, why same code builds + runs perfectly on iphone devices OR Generic iOS Device, On the other hand fails on simulator  ?**

Comment: How does your answer explain why it builds ok for simulator and not for device?  What does your comment "may be architecture are missing" actually mean?  These are Apple-supplied frameworks you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you encounter such issue, I recommend on using the 'lipo' tool of Apple. you call it like this:

```
/usr/bin/lipo -i <path-to-libraray-file>.a
```

The response will be:

```
Architectures in the fat file: <the-lib>.a are: armv7 arm64
```

I guess that in your case, the library which provides the ASIdentifierManager **will only show** *armv7* and *arm64* which are required to run on real devices, but not i386 required for the simulator.

So the question is where this library is coming from. If you got it from a 3rd party, ask them to provide a 'fat' library which include all the required architectures, including one for i386

Comment: in my case I checked with lipo and I have the architecture that I need (arm64) but still get the same error. Any thought?

Comment: if you need arm64, you are not relating to this simulator question. Anyway, make sure your framework/library is actually included into the build. Try to understand the log of the build. If you still fail, try asking a separate question

Answer (score 0):

Your mac (simulator) running on i386 architecture. If you compile your static libraries for i386 as well you will be able to use them on the simulator.

Try adding "i386" to the "Valid Architectures"